# PHP moving very slowly, how can I speed this up?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm finding that my scripts are taking much longer than I would expect to process. They are timing out over and over. I don't think my scripts (as below) are endless.

```
 // Post Variables from form to script

  $a = 49;  // variables start at w49 and go to w62
  while ($a<=62) {
     $bclass = 'b'.$a; // my naming convention for posted data
     $wclass = 'w'.$a; // my database's naming convention
     if (!empty($_POST[$wclass])) {
         ${$bclass} = $_POST[$wclass];  // post if not empty.
     }
     $a++; // cycle to next
  }

  // Handle certain forms, described by level

  if ($level === '1') {
      $x = 49;
      $query = "UPDATE users SET "; // beginning of query
        while ($x <= 56) {
          $bclass = 'b'.$x;
          $wclass = 'w'.$x;
          $j = 'A';

          if (!empty(${$bclass})) {
            if ($j = 'A') {
              $query = $query."$wclass = '${$bclass}'";
            } else {
              $query = $query.", $wclass = '${$bclass}'";
            }
            $j++;
          } else {}
        }

        $query = $query." WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1"; // end of query
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    }
```

- Am I missing something?
- Any idea on how to speed this up?
- Is there a specific section/practice that's slowing me down?

Comment: ad some basic debugging\time checking to the script, find the slow point(s)

Comment: I don't see `$x` being incremented anywhere in your `while` loop

Comment: not sure why people are downvoting OP's question; seems a little unfair? or am I missing something? ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while ($x <= 56...`

when is `$x` ever incremented? will it ever reach 56?

Comment: So that's definitely a problem. However, after fixing it, I'm still timing out. The problem is definitely in the second half of the script. Just can't seem to determine how to handle speeding it up.

Comment: Also, be careful to note the difference between assignment and comparison. `if ($j = 'A') {` tests if 'A' was assigned to $j correctly.. I think you mean `if ($j == 'A') {` (I always read == as 'is equal to', if it helps..)

Comment: Could you add an update to your question, showing your code revisions (without overwriting your original code)? Also, if you could give a general idea of what you want to achieve that would be helpful too.